# Explaining the exponent (1-alpha) for the z-score

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading through "Elements of Statistical Learning" and have come across the procedure for computing a Z-score for a parameter $\beta_j$. For the $1-2\alpha$ Z-score, we have:

$(\hat{\beta}_j - z^{1-\alpha}v_j^{1/2}\hat{\sigma}, \hat{\beta}_j + z^{1-\alpha}v_j^{1/2}\hat{\sigma})$

where we have that $v_j$ is the jth diagonal element of the matrix $X^TX$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ is the estimate of the standard deviation.

How does one explain the $(1-\alpha)$ exponent to z? I'm assuming that this has to do with taking the exponential of a standard normal random variable and working with the transformed random variable?

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't $z^{1-\alpha}$ used to denote  the $(1-\alpha)$-th quantile of a standard normal distribution in this setting?

Comment: ^^this^^ what @periwinkle said

Comment: Actually that makes sense. Thank you!